# SVG: How to ignore pointer events on transparent parts of an image

Tags: svg

I have an SVG image map embedded on an HTML page.
It contains a collection of PNG `<image>`s each wrapped in a link.
Some of these images overlap, however where the overlapping part of an image is transparent I'd like the pointer events to pass to the image underneath it.

Initially I tried using `<mask>` and an alpha filter, but masks don't allow pointer-events to pass through in the way that a `<clipPath>` would. However clipPaths can't be defined using images.

Interestingly, the [SVG 1.1 spec does mention](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty) my exact problem in passing, alluding to the fact that it may be solvable, but doesn't actually say how:

> If an author wishes to achieve an effect where the transparent parts of a mask allow pointer-events to pass to an element below, a combination of masking and clipping may be used.

So any thoughts?

NB: Looks like browsers [don't support](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311942) `pointer-events: painted` on raster images either, so that's not an option.

**Example:**
https://jsfiddle.net/a2bvrzd1/3/

Comment: I've never tested browser implementation, but doesn't the spec say further down that the default `pointer-events:visiblePainted` for raster images will only recieve events "if any pixel from the raster image which is under the pointer is not fully transparent"?

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that part -- nonetheless it seems like it doesn't work (in firefox & chrome at least) https://jsfiddle.net/a2bvrzd1/1/

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. There are many questions I could ask about your use case, that would be answered by a sample.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau Thanks, I have added my example to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG spec explicitly states that fully transparent pixels in a raster image should not cause a click event if `pointer-events="visiblePainted"` (the default) or `pointer-events="painted`.

Unfortunately, however, Chrome, Firefox, and Edge all seem to treat bitmap images as completely opaque.

If you want to encourage this to be fixed, you could star the following bug tickets:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=311942
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=806468

AFAIK, the only solution to this right now is to use a clip path.

```js
function click(evt) {
  console.log("Clicked on " + evt.target.parentElement.id);
}

document.getElementById("blue").addEventListener("click", click);
document.getElementById("red").addEventListener("click", click);
```

```html
<svg width="400" height="400">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="red-clip">
      <path d="M 100,100, 300,100, 300,300, 100,300 Z M 150,150, 150,250, 250,250, 250,150 Z"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <a id="blue">
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="400" fill="skyblue"/>
  </a>
  <a id="red">
    <image x="100" y="100" width="200" height="200"
           image-rendering="pixelated" clip-path="url(#red-clip)"
           xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,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"/>
  </a>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I correctly understood you, then the click event should pass through the upper semi-transparent image to the bottom one and trigger on it.

For these purposes, the attribute `pointer-events ="none"`

Assigning this attribute `<image id ="semi" style="pointer-events:none;"` we make the picture transparent for clicks on the red and black rectangles that are located under this picture.

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"  width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 400 400" > 


  <rect x="50" y="50" width="100" height="100" fill="black" > 
   <animate attributeName="x" from="50"  to="250" dur="2s" begin="click" fill="freeze" />
   </rect>
  
    <rect x="150" y="150" width="100" height="100" fill="red" > 
   <animate attributeName="x" from="150"  to="350" dur="2s" begin="click" fill="freeze" />
   </rect>
 
 <image id="semi" xlink:href="http://i68.tinypic.com/2wnnriv.jpg"  width="300px" height="300px" opacity="0.9" y="0" x="0" style="pointer-events:none;"/>

</svg>
```

Browser support: 
https://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Theory:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

Comment: The problem is that the image has both 100% opaque sections and 100% transparent sections, and I need the the former to capture pointer events and the latter to ignore them.

Comment: @NeonPaul Add the code to your question so that people try to solve the problem specifically. It's not clear why you have not done so yet

Comment: Thanks, I have added my example to the question.